# how to initialize FirebaseRecyclerAdapter inside populateviewholder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

im trying to get the uid from the push() in firebaserecycler adapter, but the problem is i need to initialize the firebaserecycleradapter, how can i do it?

```
 protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserViewHolder>(
                Users.class,
                R.layout.account_row,
                UserViewHolder.class,
                mRef

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.w("asd", "You clicked on "+position);


                        DatabaseReference ref = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position);

                        ref.getKey();

                        Log.w("asd", "This is the key "+ref);

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Can you describe a bit more what this recycler view is supposed to show? And also share a snippet of the JSON that it's showing (as text, no screenshot). You can get this JSON by clicking the Export JSON link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: Did you set the adapter to your recyclerView?